# Redirecting information from syslog to separate file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logs, rsyslog

I want to log all incoming TCP connections to my Ubuntu 18.04.3 system. That works fine and is not the problem, just as an intro. I am using this command in crontab for this:

`@reboot /sbin/iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --syn -j LOG --log-prefix='[tcpconnections] '`

(I know that this is not a pretty way to do it, but it's not a security matter, so I am fine with this simple way. Again, not the problem here.)

Of course this creates a lot of log lines in syslog. Therefore want to reroute the information to a seperate log file:

```
/var/log/tcpconnections.log
```

I managed to get the logging information into this separate file with creating a new file

```
/etc/rsyslog.d/tcpconnections.conf
```

with the content

```
if $msg contains "[tcpconnections]" then {
        /var/log/tcpconnections.log
        stop
}
```

and restarting the rsyslog service and/or the whole system afterwards.

**However, the log entries show up in both: in syslog AND in the separate log file.** 
As far as I know, the "stop"  should prevent that from happening.

Things I have also tried without success:

~ instead of stop but found out that this is deprecated

```
:msg,contains,"[tcpconnections] " /var/log/tcpconnections.log
   & ~
```

Pretty much any combination of the above and anything I could google on this topic.

Does anybody have an idea on where my mistake is? I would greatly appreciate any help on this, thank you all.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and forgot about processing order. You need to name your file something like `/etc/rsyslog.d/00_tcpconnections.conf` so it is processed before other rules in `/etc/rsyslog.d/`. This is an example for my ocragent script.

```
# copy to /etc/rsyslog.d/00_ocragent.conf
if ( $programname == "ocragent" ) then {
    action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/ocragent.log" flushOnTXEnd="on")
    stop
}
```