# dhcp-relay custom log file

Tags: ubuntu, dhcp, syslog

I have
**isc-dhcp-relay/xenial-updates,now 4.3.3-5ubuntu12.10 amd64 [installed]**

working good, how i can move logging this daemon from syslog to custom log file?

Comment: Try this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/555616/redirecting-information-from-syslog-to-separate-file

Answer (score 0):

You can't. What you can do is make syslog log that to a separate file (see `/etc/rsyslog.d/`).

- Create file `/etc/rsyslog.d/dhcp-relay.conf`
- Add the line `local7.* -/var/log/dhcp-relay.log`
- restart rsyslog

Also look at the file `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`, maybe you want to change the line where it logs to `/var/log/syslog` to contain local7.none to avoid double loggings.

Comment: ... using what syntax? An example would go a long way towards making this a better answer.

Comment: i do not understand your answer
if you have no knowledge why write something?

Comment: You can't select a logfile, it is what it is. This is the answer. What you can do is make syslog write the dhcp-messages to a separate file though. I edited my answer.

Comment: worked for dhcpd and not worked for dhcprelay. sorry, your misunderstuded the question. try to studying.

Comment: My first sentence stands - you cannot change the daemon behavior without fiddling with the code to log to another syslog-faciliy (used to be local<somewaht>),  now it is `system daemon`. You can write your own syslog-specs then. Start at the  [Syslog](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/) Documentation. It's not my answer bot your question.